# How to factorize the following equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have equation $2b^2 - 72b - 406=0$. I divided it with 2 and I got $b^2 - 36b - 203=0$. My teacher then wrote $(b-29)(b-7)=0$ but I don’t understand how he got that. When I try to solve that equation I get $18 \pm\sqrt{(527)}$. How did he get $29$ and $7$ and how did he factorize that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Your teacher factored $b^2-36b\color{red}+203$; note $203=7\times29$

Comment: He used that $(x+a)(x+b)=x^2+(a+b)x+ab$

Comment: How did you get $18 \pm \sqrt{527}$ in the first place?

Comment: you can see 'middle term splitting method'

Comment: Calculator, quadratic formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your teacher factored $b^2-36b\color{red}+203$.  Your teacher could have used the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), noting that $203=7\times29$, or the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), which I presume is how you got $18\pm\sqrt{527}$ for the solutions to $b^2-36b-203=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your teacher refactored the type equation mentioned above by others contributors. The answer you got for $b²-36b-203=0$ is correct. Taking $x=b$ just for common usage, and the roots you mentioned as $x_1$ and $x_2$, note that
$$(x - x_1)(x-x_2)=0$$
$$x² - (x_1+x_2)x + x_1x_2 = 0$$
$$x² - (18+\sqrt{527} + 18 - \sqrt{527})x + (18+\sqrt{527})(18-\sqrt{527}) = 0$$
$$x² - 36x + (18² - \left(\sqrt{527}\right)² = 0$$
$$x² - 36x - 203 = 0$$